# Unhandled error when exit uploading photo from react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, error-handling

Here is my Component for selecting and uploading a photo from the users phone. It´s work fine, expect when a user open the phone photolibrary but then decide to cancel and not selecting any photo to upload, i then get a error like:

" YellowBox.js:82 Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Error: User cancelled image selection "

i do not know where and how to catch and handle the error, any help ?

```
class ProfilePictureHandeler extends Component {
constructor (props) {
super(props)
this.state = {
  loading: false,
  dp: null
 }
}

openPicker () {
this.setState({ loading: true })
const Blob = RNFetchBlob.polyfill.Blob
const fs = RNFetchBlob.fs
window.XMLHttpRequest = RNFetchBlob.polyfill.XMLHttpRequest
window.Blob = Blob

const { currentUser } = firebase.auth()

ImagePicker.openPicker({
  cropping: true,
  height: 265,
  width: 265,
  mediaType: 'photo'
}).then(image => {
  const imagePath = image.path

  let uploadBlob = null

  const imageRef = firebase.storage().ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/profile`).child('dp.jpg')

  let mime = 'image/jpg'
  fs.readFile(imagePath, 'base64')
        .then((data) => {
          return Blob.build(data, { type: `${mime};BASE64` })
        })
      .then((blob) => {
        uploadBlob = blob
        return imageRef.put(blob, { contentType: mime })
      })
       .then(() => {
         uploadBlob.close()
         return imageRef.getDownloadURL()
       })
       .then((url) => {
         firebase.database().ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/profile`).update({
           profile_picture: url
         })
         let obj = {}
         obj['loading'] = false
         obj['dp'] = url
         this.setState(obj)
       })
       .catch((error) => {
         console.log(error + 'OPEN PICKER AGAIN')
       })
       .catch((error) => {
         console.log(error)
       })
       .catch((error) => {
         console.log(error)
       })
})
 }

render () {
const selectedPicture = this.state.dp ? (<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.openPicker()}>
  <Avatar
    height={265}
    rounded
    source={{ uri: this.state.dp }}
    activeOpacity={0.7}
    />
  </TouchableOpacity>) : (

  <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.openPicker()} >

    <Avatar
      rounded
      height={265}
      source={require('../../src/assets/man.png')}
      activeOpacity={0.7}
 />
  </TouchableHighlight>

 )
    // Default picture, d
const standardPicture = this.state.loading ? <ActivityIndicator animating={this.state.loading} /> : (
  <View>
    {selectedPicture}
  </View>
)

return (
  <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.openPicker()} >
    <View>
      {standardPicture}
    </View>
  </TouchableHighlight>

 )
 }
}

export default ProfilePictureHandeler
```

Comment: can you pls create a fiddle

Answer (score 3):

`ImagePicker.openPicker()` will throw an error if user cancelled selecting image.

Try to add a `catch` to you code like this:

```
ImagePicker.openPicker(options)
.then(image => {
    // do your stuff
})
.catch(error => {
    // add this to your code
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a fix that worked for me:

```js
ImagePicker.openPicker({
      width: 300,
      height: 400,
      cropping: true,
    })
.then(image => {
    /*
image = {
    "cropRect": { "height": zzz, "width": sss, "x": aaa, "y": qqq },
    "height": xxx,
    "mime": "image/jpeg",
    "modificationDate": "1611843171000",
    "path": "file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/.../.....jpg",
    "size": 59579,
    "width": yyy
}
    */
})
.catch(error => {
    if (error.code === 'E_PICKER_CANCELLED') { // here the solution
      return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ImagePicker.openPicker({
  cropping: true,
  height: 265,
  width: 265,
  mediaType: 'photo'
}).then(image => {
  const imagePath = image.path

  let uploadBlob = null

  const imageRef = firebase.storage().ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/profile`).child('dp.jpg')

  let mime = 'image/jpg'
  fs.readFile(imagePath, 'base64')
        .then((data) => {
          return Blob.build(data, { type: `${mime};BASE64` })
        })
      .then((blob) => {
        uploadBlob = blob
        return imageRef.put(blob, { contentType: mime })
      })
       .then(() => {
         uploadBlob.close()
         return imageRef.getDownloadURL()
       })
       .then((url) => {
         firebase.database().ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/profile`).update({
           profile_picture: url
         })
         let obj = {}
         obj['loading'] = false
         obj['dp'] = url
         this.setState(obj)
       })
       .catch((error) => {
         console.log(error + 'OPEN PICKER AGAIN')
       })
       .catch((error) => {
         console.log(error)
       })
       .catch((error) => {
         console.log(error)
       })
}).catch((callBack)=>{ // you forgot to add catch to this promise.
   console.log(callBack); // Please handle the callBack here.
  });
 }
```

Comment: ah thanks man ! Do you have any clue of handel the problem here ? i would like to "this.setState({loading: false})" ..

 like callback(this.setState({loading: false}))

Comment: I can if i know what data does 'callBack' has. You can add `this.setState({loading:false})` in place of console.log and I recommend you to give a toast message with the message you get it from "callBack".

Comment: If this answer solved your issue then i would be appreciated if you could close this question by accepting my answer. Thank you :)